# Compare public API of .NET assembly to determine backward compatibility

Tags: .net, versioning, compatibility, .net-assembly

Before I go ahead and roll my own does a tool exist that will compare the public API of one assembly with another to determine if one is backward compatible the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely - simple answer - we use this tool: [BitDiffer](http://www.bitwidgets.com/)

Comment: That looks like what I'm after, thanks.  I think the next is to integrate into our CI build (Team City) so commits that break the backward compatibility of a given assembly but do not increment the major version (we are applying semver.org) fail to build.

Comment: is there a free (or better: open-source) tool to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a tool that performs that specific requirement. However, I believe that [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) does have an SQL-like syntax that you can use to build queries against .NET assembles. So for example you could query something that does a diff on the public members of each assembly and see what the differences are?

http://www.ndepend.com/doc_vs_diff.aspx

You could try NDepend out (I think it has a trial version) and see if it helps you out. Lets us know how it works out for you.